# Directory Security

Tags: c#, security, directory-security

My app is creating a directory so that I can store log files in it. I'm adding user security to the directory, but I don't know how to make it propagate. For example, I'm adding the user `everyone` to the directory, with `read` and `write` access, but when my app then create a log file in this directory, the log file has not inherited the `everyone` security (read, write).

What am I missing?

```
DirectorySecurity dirSec = Directory.GetAccessControl(_dbPath);
dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow));
dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, AccessControlType.Allow));
dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.CreateFiles, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(_dbPath, dirSec);
```

Comment: Beware that "Everyone" won't work if the system is not running in English, as this name is localized on other systems (e.g. "Tout le monde" on a French OS). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298905/add-everyone-privilege-to-folder-using-c-net for a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there.  The thing you're missing is the [AuthorizationRule.InheritanceFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.authorizationrule.inheritanceflags.aspx) flag - by default ACEs aren't inheritable, but if you add the InheritanceFlags attribute the ACEs will become inheritable.

Answer (score 0):

In MSDN under the DirectorySecurity it has this line:

```
Use the FileSecurity class to retrieve, add, or change the access rules that represent the DACL and SACL of a file.
```

I think that is what you need to look at to change the ACL of a file...

MSDN Ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx