# How can I set a file to be writeable by all users?

Tags: c#, file, permissions

I want to set a file to be writeable by all users.

```
FileSecurity sec = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

string users = ?????;
sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(
        users,
        FileSystemRights.Write, 
        AccessControlType.Allow));

File.SetAccessControl(fileName, sec);
```

The problem is that I don't know which string to use. I have tried `users = WindowsAccountType.Normal.ToString()`, but that only gives `"Normal"`, which doesn't work. How can I get the string that designates the group of all users on a machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are looking for the "Everyone" group which all logged-on users belong to. However using the string "Everyone" will get you into serious trouble on non-english systems

A much better solution is to use it via SecurityIdentifier WellKnownSidType.WorldSid:

```
SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
```

The complete solution is already described in this answer: [Add "Everyone" privilege to folder using C#.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298905/add-everyone-privilege-to-folder-using-c-net/5398398#5398398)

Answer (score 4):

try "Everyone" which is a system account defined on every machine or even on the AD domain if any (DOMAIN\Everyone in that case)