# Creating New Folder with Everyone rights using C#

Tags: c#

I Want to create a new folder with everyone access rights in "C:\Program Files" and this should work out in all OS.can any body provide your support in implementing the above scenario using C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298905/add-everyone-privilege-to-folder-using-c-net

Comment: _Show your effort first_.. What have you tried so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some sample codes:

http://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/

This can be achieved through defining new ACL-s on folder / files.

Cheers

Comment: string strPath = @"C:\Program Files\ABC";
                DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);
                DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
                dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                                InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
                                PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
                dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);  when trying this exception is thrown