# How to add local service priviledge on folder by C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

i was finding how to programmatically add local service priviledge on folder in `C:\Program Files` by C# and got a write up from this url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298905/add-everyone-privilege-to-folder-using-c-net/5398398#5398398`

they show how to do this for `everyone` user.

```
DirectorySecurity sec = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
// Using this instead of the "Everyone" string means we work on non-English systems.
SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.Modify | FileSystemRights.Synchronize, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(path, sec);
```

**just tell me what i need to change in above code as a result `local service` privilege will be add on a specific folder.**

i develop a windows service which will create a folder and xml file in it at run time. when i install my service from setup file then folder is not getting created but no error is also return.

so i debug the service and saw it could create folder and xml file in it during debugging time. the issue is occurred when i install the service from setup file. i am not being able to capture the issue like what problem is occuring. so guide me what should i do to capture the issue like "Why my service not being able to create folder and file " looking for guidance. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalServiceSid, null);
```

or

```
new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-19");
```

Comment: what is the meaning of this `S-1-5-19`

Comment: [SID structure for LOCAL SERVICE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980032.aspx).