# How to modify file access control in .NET Core

Tags: c#, file-permissions, .net-core

I'm trying to change the permissions of a file in .NET Core.
However, it seems that [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have any `SetAccessControl` anymore.

```
// Create a new FileInfo object.
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(FileName);

// Get a FileSecurity object that represents the 
// current security settings.
FileSecurity fSecurity = fInfo.GetAccessControl();

// Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                Rights,
                                                ControlType));

// Set the new access settings.
fInfo.SetAccessControl(fSecurity);
```

The goal is just to add execution right to the current owner of a file (which is not Windows or Unix specific feature).

Any clues on how to do that on .NET Core ?

Comment: What would you expect to happen on Unix, which has a different access control system? Or is this a Windows-only .Net Core application?

Comment: @svick I would expect something like a common subset. I will check what has been done (if it has been done) on Mono.

Comment: With new versions of .NET (6+) this code works as-is. There is no System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl assembly to add.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## How to Get and modify User Group Other Rights on Windows

I finally implement the Windows file permission access:

**1. Get the file security:**

```
      var security = new FileSecurity(fileSystemInfoFullName, 
                AccessControlSections.Owner | 
                AccessControlSections.Group |
                AccessControlSections.Access);
```

**2. Get the authorization rules:**

```
var authorizationRules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
```

**3. Get the authorization rules for the owner:**

```
var owner = security.GetOwner(typeof(NTAccount));
foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in authorizationRules)
{
    FileSystemAccessRule fileRule = rule as FileSystemAccessRule;
    if (fileRule != null)
    {
        if (owner != null && fileRule.IdentityReference == owner)
        {
             if (fileRule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile) ||
                fileRule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute) ||
                fileRule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.FullControl))
            {
                ownerRights.IsExecutable = true;
            }
        }
        else if (group != null && fileRule.IdentityReference == group)
        {
            // TO BE CONTINUED...
        }
    }
}
```

**4. Add a rule for owner:**

```
security.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add,
    new FileSystemAccessRule(owner, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow),
    out bool modified);
```

**5. Bonus**

How to get the `group` and `others`, or ... my definition of something equivalent ?

```
var group = security.GetGroup(typeof(NTAccount));

var others = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null)
                 .Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
```

*Note: This code comes from my open source project [Lx.Shell](https://github.com/leoxialtd/Leoxia.Shell)*

Comment: This blows... why did they have to make it so much more complicated?  Why not some extension methods on DirectoryInfo and FileInfo?

Comment: This works on UNIX: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132081/file-permissions-on-linux-unix-with-net-core

Comment: what are 'ownerRights' and 'group' in your code?

Answer (score 32):

The `FileSecurity` class is now part of the [System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/) package for .NET Core. There is no longer a `File.GetAccessControl` method so you will need to instantiate the `FileSecurity` instance yourself.

Comment: As an aside, creating a new .NET Core 2.0 Library will not include this assembly.  You will have to add the `System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl` as a NuGet package.

Comment: @Scyssion Yes, my comment says that.

Comment: An example would help massively. I can't find a working example for .net core anywhere.

Comment: @Learner Check the [unit tests project in the Github repository](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/tests) for examples

Comment: Note that unlike .NET Core API, that package does NOT support long file name. Check my additional answer below for details.

Answer (score 28):

At this time there are two extension methods: `GetAccessControl` and `SetAccessControl`, for `FileInfo`, `DirectoryInfo` and etc.

So you can use `var ac = new FileInfo(path).GetAccessControl()`, this expression is valid both in .NET Framework and .Net Core. But you still need `dotnet add package System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl`.

`File.GetAccessControl` isn't available in .NET Core.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemaclextensions.getaccesscontrol

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, so much easier to use

Answer (score 5):

The documentation says this IS supported and it works (for me). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemaclextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1 DOES have a SetAccessControl method

Be sure to add the `System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl` NuGet package.

Here's what I had in .NET Framework:

```
var ds = new DirectorySecurity();
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(adminSI, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
ds.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false); // disable inheritance and clear any inherited permissions

Directory.SetAccessControl(<path to directory>, ds);
```

And here's what it is working in .NET Core 3.1. Only the last line is different:

```
var ds = new DirectorySecurity();
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(adminSI, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
ds.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false); // disable inheritance and clear any inherited permissions

System.IO.FileSystemAclExtensions.SetAccessControl(new DirectoryInfo(<path to directory>), ds);
```

Comment: note that: 'DirectorySecurity' is only supported on: 'windows' and you will get 'CA1416: Validate platform compatibility' warning

Answer (score 2):

This is to add to other answers. Note that the `GetAccessControl` and `SetAccessControl` in the `System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl` does **NOT** support long file name (255 chars) like other .NET Core `System.IO` APIs.

The exception you receive is `ArgumentException` thrown by internal calls, the parameter is `name`.

If you are using that package, you need to add this if you may find long file name:

```
if (usingFile.FullName.Length > 255)
{
    usingFile = new FileInfo(@"\\?\" + file.FullName);
}
```

or

```
if (folder.FullName.Length > 255)
{
    folder = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\?\" + folder.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following what @jon-r said, I was able to get mine working. This is still relevant in .NET 7. This is using `System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl` and `System.IO` NuGet packages.

My .NET Framework 4.8 code:

```
var ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(dir);
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(dir, ds);
```

My .NET 7 code:

```
var ds = new DirectorySecurity();
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
System.IO.FileSystemAclExtensions.SetAccessControl(new DirectoryInfo(dir), ds);
```

My initial code looked a little different than Jon's so I wanted to include it for others.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle acls for directory or file:

```
       // Adds an ACL entry on the specified directory for the specified account.
    public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
    {
        // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
        // current security settings.
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                        Rights,
                                                        ControlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
    }

    // Removes an ACL entry on the specified directory for the specified account.
    public static void RemoveDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
    {
        // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
        // current security settings.
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
        dSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                        Rights,
                                                        ControlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
    }

    // Adds an ACL entry on the specified file for the specified account.
    public static void AddFileSecurity(string fileName, string account,
        FileSystemRights rights, AccessControlType controlType)
    {

        // Create a new FileInfo object.
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

        // Get a FileSecurity object that represents the 
        // current security settings.
        FileSecurity fSecurity = fInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.
        fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
            rights, controlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        fInfo.SetAccessControl(fSecurity);
    }

    // Removes an ACL entry on the specified file for the specified account.
    public static void RemoveFileSecurity(string fileName, string account,
        FileSystemRights rights, AccessControlType controlType)
    {

        // Create a new FileInfo object.
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

        // Get a FileSecurity object that represents the 
        // current security settings.
        FileSecurity fSecurity = fInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Remove the FileSystemAccessRule from the security settings.
        fSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
            rights, controlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        fInfo.SetAccessControl(fSecurity);
    }

    //example for open onClick folderdialog and get owner by NTACCOUNT of folder from acl
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (folder != null)
        {
            // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder
            // (including other sub-folder contents)
            Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.
            FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);

            // Create a new FileInfo object.
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(folder.ToString());

            // Get a FileSecurity object that represents the 
            // current security settings.
            FileSecurity fSecurity = fInfo.GetAccessControl();

            IdentityReference identityReference = fSecurity.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            NTAccount ntAccount = identityReference.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount;
            var fileOwner = ntAccount.Value;


            //do something with file Owner
            //this.tb1.Text = "folder: " + folder.Name + " in Pfad: " + folder.Path + "owned by: " + fileOwner;
        }
        else
        {
            //error Handler
        }

    }
```

Comment: As the original question says ... Net Core no longer has GetAccessControl or SetAccessControl methods on DirectoryInfo

Comment: The GetAccessControl and SetAccessControl have been completely withdrawn from Net Core 3.0 and above, it will work in 2.2 though. If you tried to run it you'd get a Method Not Found exception (or something-like). I have a multi-targettting project with exactly this problem, it works on Framework 4.7.2 and Core 2.2, but fails on Core 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: Then it was from a 2.2. project. Thank you