# File permissions on Linux/Unix with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to learn how to set file permissions on Linux/Unix with .NET Core.  I already found a question on here that points me in the direction of System.IO.FileSystem, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use it.

In a nutshell, I'd like to chmod a file 644 from a .NET Core application that only runs on Linux, but am at a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: Microsoft uses their file permission model on Windows and translates it to Linux/UNIX. So the call to `chmod` is internal, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/bffef76f6af208e2042a2f27bc081ee908bb390b/src/Common/src/Interop/Unix/System.Native/Interop.ChMod.cs and is used only in https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/801dde95a5eac06140d0ac633ac3f9bfdd25aca5/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystemInfo.Unix.cs So in your case, you must translate 644 to the corresponding Windows file permissions and then use the Windows way to manipulate the file.

Comment: I've solved this issue calling `/bin/chmod` directly using `System.Diagnostics` API

Answer (score 47, accepted):

At the moment, there is no built in API in .NET Core for this. However, the .NET Core team is working to make `Mono.Posix` available on .NET Core. This exposes API to do this kind of operation in managed code. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/15289 and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3186. You can try an early version of this API here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/1.0.0-beta1

```
    var unixFileInfo = new Mono.Unix.UnixFileInfo("test.txt");
    // set file permission to 644
    unixFileInfo.FileAccessPermissions =
        FileAccessPermissions.UserRead | FileAccessPermissions.UserWrite
        | FileAccessPermissions.GroupRead
        | FileAccessPermissions.OtherRead;
```

If you don't want to use Mono.Posix, you can implement this same functionality by invoking native code. Using P/Invoke, you can call the `chmod` function from `libc`. See `man 2 chmod` for more details on the native API.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using static System.Console;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int chmod(string pathname, int mode);

    // user permissions
    const int S_IRUSR = 0x100;
    const int S_IWUSR = 0x80;
    const int S_IXUSR = 0x40;

    // group permission
    const int S_IRGRP = 0x20;
    const int S_IWGRP = 0x10;
    const int S_IXGRP = 0x8;

    // other permissions
    const int S_IROTH = 0x4;
    const int S_IWOTH = 0x2;
    const int S_IXOTH = 0x1;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine("Setting permissions to 0755 on test.sh");
        const int _0755 =
            S_IRUSR | S_IXUSR | S_IWUSR
            | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP
            | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH;
        WriteLine("Result = " + chmod(Path.GetFullPath("test.sh"), (int)_0755));

        WriteLine("Setting permissions to 0644 on sample.txt");
        const int _0644 =
            S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR
            | S_IRGRP
            | S_IROTH;
        WriteLine("Result = " + chmod(Path.GetFullPath("sample.txt"), _0644));

        WriteLine("Setting permissions to 0600 on secret.txt");
        const int _0600 = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
        WriteLine("Result = " + chmod(Path.GetFullPath("secret.txt"), _0600));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note - the NuGet package is out of beta: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/

Comment: I found that I had to issue `unixFileInfo.Refresh()` to immediately commit the changes to the file system. Otherwise the changes would manifest some unspecified time later. Curious if anyone else has seen that?

Comment: Are you running the native code sample using .NetCore?

Answer (score 18):

I solved this problem by just starting a new process and executing bash `chmod` commands.

**Example:**

```
public static void Exec(string cmd)
{
    var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
        
    using var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "/bin/bash",
            Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\""
        }
    };

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

and then:

```
Exec("chmod 644 /path/to/file.txt");
```

You can also use this `Exec` method to run any other type of bash commands.

Answer (score 16):

I know this question is a bit old, but for .NET 7 and above, there's an easier API.

```
File.SetUnixFileMode(path, UnixFileMode.UserRead | UnixFileMode.UserWrite);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple chmod function that you can use in c# with no depencencies.

```
// Returns true if success and false otherwise
// permissions can be an int or a string. For example it can also be +x, -x etc..
bool Chmod(string filePath, string permissions = "700", bool recursive = false)
{
        string cmd;
        if (recursive)
            cmd = $"chmod -R {permissions} {filePath}";
        else
            cmd = $"chmod {permissions} {filePath}";

        try
        {
            using (Process proc = Process.Start("/bin/bash", $"-c \"{cmd}\""))
            {
                proc.WaitForExit();
                return proc.ExitCode == 0;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: The original post is from a couple of years ago, so checking in to see if there are other alternatives available to "bash/chmod" and Mono.Postix package.