# Find linux file types with dotnet core

Tags: c#, linux, file, .net-core

I'm trying to calculate the HASH for a given file in linux system by using c# dotnet core 2.0.

How ever, when i am getting a file (i know it's not a real file) from other type such like:

> character device file |  block device | local socket |  named pipe.

I cant calculate the HASH for those file and it's It only makes sense cause those are not real files.

So, my question is how can i find that the given path it's not a regular file, so i can skip the HASH calculation.

example: for now i'm using `FileAttributes` to determine the file type,
The file im trying to calculte is at the path `/dev/kmsg`

```
crw-r--r--. 1 root root 1, 11 Aug  1 03:05 /dev/kmsg
```

code:

```
Log.Debug($"pathInfo.Attributes.ToString: {pathInfo.Attributes.ToString()}");
```

the output is:

```
 pathInfo.Attributes.ToString: Normal
```

any idea to find out the file type ?

Thanks

Comment: Related, see [File permissions on Linux/Unix with .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45132081/608639)

Comment: @jww thanks , but it dos not seems like what i was looking for. my intention it to find the file type and not to set permission. i read all the thread and links you pointed , but there is not mention for the 'file type'..