# How to get Linux file permissions in .NET 5 / .NET 6 without Mono.Posix with p/invoke?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, pinvoke, libc

I recently found, that I can make Linux system calls from .NET relatively easy.

For example, to see if I need `sudo` I just make a signature like this:

```cs
internal class Syscall {

[DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern uint geteuid();

// ...
}
```

```
public static bool IsRoot => Syscall.geteuid() == 0;
```

Neat. So much easier and faster than everything else, right?
This is the simplest possible system call, other use strings and structures.

After some digging in the documentation and testing for myself, I found that strings from `libc` can be mapped directly to `string` from `char*` by default marshaller, most of the other stuff require just using some fun with manually mapping `IntPtr` to structures.

So in similar way I quickly mapped `chmod`, `chown`, `lchown`, `getgrnam`, `getpwnam`, `getuid`, `symlink`. All tested on my Ubuntu VM, works.

I even made my own super neat `Chmod` implementation that works identically to shell `chmod` that accepts relative permissions like `u+wX`. And walks through the filesystem.

And that's where I lost a night. I needed original permissions, and I read they can be obtained with `stat` call. What could possibly go wrong?

First I made `Stat` structure using `Linux` manual documentation:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html

Then I made the appropriate `extern`.

First surprise: the entry point not found.

I digged, and digged and digged some more. Until I just opened my `libc` binary and searched for something similar to `stat`. Bingo! I found `__xstat` point. That was it, I changed my signature, I read in documentation that beside specifying `ver` parameter (that should be set to `3`) - it should work **identical** to `stat`.

It didn't. The call passes, but it always return -1, does not return `Stat` structure.

Then I found some sources of the `__xstat` where it checks if the `ver` parameter matches the kernel version. WEIRD! But I tried passing `5`. Because it's the current kernel version I use. Also some other numbers like '3' and '0'. No luck. Nothing works. I also tested `__xstat64`. Same result, I mean no result.

Then I found a discussion on GitHub between `.NET` developers, that calling `stat` is super tricky, because it's different on every kernel. Wait, **WHAT!?**

Yes, I know it is in `Mono.Posix.NETStandard 1.0.0` package, I use it and it works. (And that's what the guys recommended.)

But since I'm just learning platform invoke "voodoo" - I just cannot leave it like that. Why everything but the `stat` call works without any problem, why is there the exception? It is a completely BASIC thing. Then after "why" comes "HOW?".

They did it in `Mono`. I digged in `Mono` sources on GitHub to find, that it's one of the few function not actually called from `libc` but from their own assembly in C:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/support/sys-stat.c

Interesting, but I still struggle to understand how it works.

BTW, adding `Mono` to my project increased my compiled executable Linux x64 file from 200kb to 1200kb. To add literally 1 function of reading a single number! BTW, it has a license issue, package signature says `MIT`, source file linked says `MPL`. And my package is asking users to accept this curious license. I mean, to accept `MIT`, though I'm not quite sure whether it's really `MIT` or `MPL`. My own package uses `MIT`.

So - what are the (other) catches and gotchas when calling `libc` from dotnet? Is there a simpler way to call `stat()`? Is there an alternative route to get the permissions from `.NET`? I figured out the `.NET` itself DOES that internally. It gets the file permissions obtainable from `FileInfo`. However, the attributed are "translated" to Windows structure, and most of the information is lost in translation.

My last try:

```cs
[DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int __xstat(int ver, string path, out Stat stat);

internal struct Stat {

    public ulong st_dev;        // device
    public ulong st_ino;        // inode
    public uint st_mode;        // protection
    public ulong st_nlink;      // number of hard links
    public uint st_uid;         // user ID of owner
    public uint st_gid;         // group ID of owner
    public ulong st_rdev;       // device type (if inode device)
    public long st_size;        // total size, in bytes
    public long st_blksize;     // blocksize for filesystem I/O
    public long st_blocks;      // number of blocks allocated
    public long st_atime;       // time of last access
    public long st_mtime;       // time of last modification
    public long st_ctime;       // time of last status change
    public long st_atime_nsec;  // Timespec.tv_nsec partner to st_atime
    public long st_mtime_nsec;  // Timespec.tv_nsec partner to st_mtime
    public long st_ctime_nsec;  // Timespec.tv_nsec partner to st_ctime

}
```

Called like `Syscall.__xstat(5, path, out Stat stat)`. Returns `-1` for any path I tried.

Of course

```cs
public static Permissions GetPermissions(string path) {
    if (Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.stat(path, out var stat) != 0) throw new InvalidOperationException($"Stat call failed for {path}");
    return new Permissions((uint)stat.st_mode);
}
```

works. It only takes 1MB more ;) I know, it's nothing, but I have external dependency just for 1 simple function.

From what I researched - the `Stat` structure differs from kernel to kernel. I suspect if I tried some other versions, one would finally work, but it doesn't solve the problem at all, because it can stop working after an update on target machine.

My guess is when the structure is required and allowed to change in Linux, there must be a kind of common interface / compatibility mechanism allowing users to get permissions without detailed knowledge about system and library versions on a specific target machine.

I thought `libc` was just something like that, but it seems like either it's not exactly it, or there is a bit higher level interface somewhere else in Linux and I don't mean shell here ;)

I have mainly Windows background, I used Windows p/invoke a lot. Most of the code I wrote for Windows 7 still works on Windows 11. Old `Win32` calls haven't changed, except some very system UI specific ones.

Comment: You need to pass "1" as version on 64-bit architecture (not 3 or 5). "stat" would hide all that complexity from your, but it's unfortunately basically a macros so that helps if you write C code but not if you pinvoke.

Comment: I get "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Thank you for this @Harry. It would be interesting to see the results from the other POSIX-related calls you mapped to .NET P/Invoke. You don't happen to have them available in a GitHub repo somewhere? :)

Comment: @PerLundberg https://github.com/HTD/Woof.LinuxAdmin - legacy version. The whole toolkit is rewritten with major changes and will be released maybe even this weekend, with the new sources (the current repository is private until stable and tested enough to publish). There are not many POSIX calls, I was more focused on automating the tasks of installing Linux system daemons and the quick configuration of RPI boards. The Toolkit has more tools handy for Linux admin apps.

Comment: All this convo about https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/19958 was an amusing read. I almost get now why Microsoft made `kernel32.dll` ABI fixed, its so much easier to do Interop instead of doing native processor syscalls. POSIX defines syscalls, but doesn't define ABI, so, WTF. Then you have libc wich defines the ABI, fun thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I was wrong posting the last answer. I found out, the `libc` binary contained something like __xstat and I called it.

Wrong! As the name would suggest, it was a kind of a private function, something intended to be an implementation detail, not a part of the API.

So I found another function with a normal name: `statx`. It does exactly what I need, it is well(-ish) documented here:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html

Here's the structure and values:
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/bits/statx.h.html
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/io/fcntl.h.html

TL;DR - it works.

I figured out that -100 (`AT_FDCWD`) passed as `dirfd` parameter makes relative paths relative to the current working directory.

I also figured out that passing zeros as flags works (as equivalent to `AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT`), and the function returns what it should for a regular local filesystem.

So here's the code:

```cs
[DllImport(LIBC, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int statx(int dirfd, string path, int flags, uint mask, out Statx data);

/// <summary>
/// POSIX statx data structure.
/// </summary>
internal struct Statx {

    /// <summary>
    /// Mask of bits indicating filled fields.
    /// </summary>
    internal uint Mask;
    /// <summary>
    /// Block size for filesystem I/O.
    /// </summary>
    internal uint BlockSize;
    /// <summary>
    /// Extra file attribute indicators
    /// </summary>
    internal ulong Attributes;
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of hard links.
    /// </summary>
    internal uint HardLinks;
    /// <summary>
    /// User ID of owner.
    /// </summary>
    internal uint Uid;
    /// <summary>
    /// Group ID of owner.
    /// </summary>
    internal uint Gid;
    /// <summary>
    /// File type and mode.
    /// </summary>
    internal ushort Mode;
    private ushort Padding01;
    /// <summary>
    /// Inode number.
    /// </summary>
    internal ulong Inode;
    /// <summary>
    /// Total size in bytes.
    /// </summary>
    internal ulong Size;
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of 512B blocks allocated.
    /// </summary>
    internal ulong Blocks;
    /// <summary>
    /// Mask to show what's supported in <see cref="Attributes"/>.
    /// </summary>
    internal ulong AttributesMask;
    /// <summary>
    /// Last access time.
    /// </summary>
    internal StatxTimeStamp AccessTime;
    /// <summary>
    /// Creation time.
    /// </summary>
    internal StatxTimeStamp CreationTime;
    /// <summary>
    /// Last status change time.
    /// </summary>
    internal StatxTimeStamp StatusChangeTime;
    /// <summary>
    /// Last modification time.
    /// </summary>
    internal StatxTimeStamp LastModificationTime;
    internal uint RDevIdMajor;
    internal uint RDevIdMinor;
    internal uint DevIdMajor;
    internal uint DevIdMinor;
    internal ulong MountId;
    private ulong Padding02;
    private ulong Padding03;
    private ulong Padding04;
    private ulong Padding05;
    private ulong Padding06;
    private ulong Padding07;
    private ulong Padding08;
    private ulong Padding09;
    private ulong Padding10;
    private ulong Padding11;
    private ulong Padding12;
    private ulong Padding13;
    private ulong Padding14;
    private ulong Padding15;
}

/// <summary>
/// Time stamp structure used by statx.
/// </summary>
public struct StatxTimeStamp {

    /// <summary>
    /// Seconds since the Epoch (UNIX time).
    /// </summary>
    public long Seconds;

    /// <summary>
    /// Nanoseconds since <see cref="Seconds"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public uint Nanoseconds;

}
```