# How to get file attributes (size, created, modified, ...) asynchronously in .NET

Tags: .net, asynchronous, filesystems

In .NET, we can use the [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-7.0) class to access metadata from the filesystem.

The `FileInfo` API is synchronous. I want to create a cache of file timestamps, and expect a high level of concurrent access. Being synchronous, the delay would result in a lot of contention in my scenario.

Is there a way to get file attributes asynchronously in .NET? P/Invoke would be acceptable as a last resort.

Comment: I posted this question as I found no discussion on the topic online.

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach, not sure if it will be applicable in your scenario, but it works. Using *Proccess* and *stat* command, in case if you are using linux environment.

```cs
    public static async Task<DateTime> GetFileTimeStamp(string path)
    {
        var p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("stat", path) { RedirectStandardOutput = true });

        await p.WaitForExitAsync();

        var timestamp = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
            .Split(Environment.NewLine)[4]
            .Replace("Access: ", "");

        return DateTime.Parse(timestamp);
    }
```

Here is an example *stat* output for reference:

```bash
  File: AsyncFileAttr.csproj
  Size: 249             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 830h/2096d      Inode: 110252      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  john)   Gid: ( 1000/  john)
Access: 2022-12-11 18:20:54.784999000 +0200
Modify: 2022-12-11 18:20:54.684999000 +0200
Change: 2022-12-11 18:20:54.684999000 +0200
 Birth: -
```

Another option is to use *statx* method from *libc* using interop, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69779224/6482931), it isn't async but it really fast.

```cs
    public static DateTime GetFileTimeStampInterop(string path)
    {
        var fileInfo = new Statx();
        statx(0, path, AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, ((uint)Mask.STATX_ALL), out fileInfo);

        // convert linux epoch to date time
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
            .AddSeconds(fileInfo.CreationTime.Seconds);
    }
```

Where *statx* is:

```cs
    [DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int statx(int dirfd, string path, int flags, uint mask, out Statx data);
```

And *Masks*\*AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT* are taken from *stat.h*, those define which info is being populated by *statx* method:

```cs
    // taken from stat.h
    // STATX_TYPE           0x00000001U     /* Want/got stx_mode & S_IFMT */
    // STATX_MODE           0x00000002U     /* Want/got stx_mode & ~S_IFMT */
    // STATX_NLINK          0x00000004U     /* Want/got stx_nlink */
    // STATX_UID            0x00000008U     /* Want/got stx_uid */
    // STATX_GID            0x00000010U     /* Want/got stx_gid */
    // STATX_ATIME          0x00000020U     /* Want/got stx_atime */
    // STATX_MTIME          0x00000040U     /* Want/got stx_mtime */
    // STATX_CTIME          0x00000080U     /* Want/got stx_ctime */
    // STATX_INO            0x00000100U     /* Want/got stx_ino */
    // STATX_SIZE           0x00000200U     /* Want/got stx_size */
    // STATX_BLOCKS         0x00000400U     /* Want/got stx_blocks */
    // STATX_BASIC_STATS    0x000007ffU     /* The stuff in the normal stat struct */
    // STATX_BTIME          0x00000800U     /* Want/got stx_btime */
    // STATX_ALL            0x00000fffU     /* All currently supported flags */
    // STATX__RESERVED              0x80000000U     /* Reserved for future struct statx expansion */
    internal enum Mask : uint
    {
        STATX_ALL = 0x00000fffU,
    }

    private static int AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT = 0x0000;
```

You can see *Statx* struct definition in the linked answer.

**Update**
Some benchmarks of *interop* vs *FileInfo* class

- Interop code under test (consider stuff posted above)

  ```cs
  public void GetFileAttrsViaInterop(string path)
  {
      var fileInfo = new Statx();
      statx(0, path, AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, ((uint)Mask.STATX_ALL), out fileInfo);
  }
  ```
- Regular *FileInfo* approach under test

  ```cs
  public void GetFileAttrsViaFileInfo(string path)
  {
      // added actual info retrieval, to be sure
      var creationTime = new FileInfo(path).CreationTimeUtc;
  }
  ```

Here are results, not sure how correct my benchmark is, I ran it on a single file via [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet):

```bash
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.2, OS=ubuntu 20.04
Intel Core i7-10850H CPU 2.70GHz, 1 CPU, 2 logical cores and 1 physical core
.NET SDK=6.0.403
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.11 (6.0.1122.52304), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.11 (6.0.1122.52304), X64 RyuJIT AVX2


|                  Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|------------------------ |---------:|---------:|---------:|
|  GetFileAttrsViaInterop | 728.9 ns | 19.18 ns | 55.65 ns |
| GetFileAttrsViaFileInfo | 446.4 ns |  8.77 ns | 10.76 ns |
```

It looks like native c# *FileInfo* is faster. Have to consider using *Refresh()* method on a *FileInfo* class for update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case I need to check potentially thousands of files, so spawning a process for each check is going to introduce a lot of overhead, especially on Windows. I'll investigate the libc approach.

Comment: So interop is much better, I've ran a simple benchmark and interop was like 1us per call comparing to 700us of launching  a separate process.

Comment: Can you add a `FileInfo` case to your benchmark to see how it compares with your hand-rolled interop code? I suspect the results would vary by platform.

Comment: @DrewNoakes sure thing, I'll do it in my spare time soon.