# How to check is a path is a file with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

This is a seemingly simple question however I could not find a satisfactory solution yet.

```
let f = FileInfo(e)
let fileFlag = f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Normal)
logger <| sprintf "%s :: %A :: %A" e fileFlag f.Attributes
```

This produces the following output:

```
/tmp/com.apple.launchd.qq7qSI6dyD/Listeners :: true :: Normal
```

To my surprise the path is a socket:

```
> file /tmp/com.apple.launchd.qq7qSI6dyD/Listeners
/tmp/com.apple.launchd.qq7qSI6dyD/Listeners: socket
```

According to the [FileAttributes Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-6.0) documentation:

> Normal     128
>
> The file is a standard file that has no special attributes. This attribute is valid only if it is used alone. `Normal` is supported on Windows, Linux, and macOS.

Is there a way to check is a path really a normal file (not a socket, not a symlink, not a device, etc.).

For example in Python:

```
> python -c "import os; import sys; print(os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]))"
/tmp/com.apple.launchd.qq7qSI6dyD/Listeners
False
```

Elaborating more:

```
> stat -f "%N: %HT%SY" /tmp/**/*
/tmp/b: Symbolic Link -> a
/tmp/com.apple.launchd.qq7qSI6dyD: Directory
/tmp/com.apple.launchd.qq7qSI6dyD/Listeners: Socket
/tmp/fseventsd-uuid: Regular File
/tmp/powerlog: Directory
/tmp/test: Regular File
/tmp/tmux-501: Directory
/tmp/tmux-501/default: Socket
```

Comment: Isn't sockets, devices, symlinks, etc, all _types_ of file, in the same way that a `.txt` file is?

Comment: I want the exact copy of the behaviour of os.path.isfile from Python.

Comment: That seems like a runtime bug to me.  A socket shouldn't have the attribute Normal IMO.  You might want to submit that as an issue on Github.

Comment: Under the hood, python's [`isfile`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Lib/genericpath.py#L27) uses the .[`stat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Lib/nntplib.py#L731) program to determine that information. I don't think there's a native equvilent to that in .Net Core yet - but it might exist in [Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132081/file-permissions-on-linux-unix-with-net-core).

Comment: Yep, stat like behaviour would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File permissions on Linux/Unix with .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132081/file-permissions-on-linux-unix-with-net-core)

Comment: No. I do not need permissions I need stat like behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today (2021.12.16) there is no way in .net to identify files in the POSIX sense.

The workaround is to use Mono.Unix the following way:

```ml
open Mono.Unix

let fileStat =
    UnixFileSystemInfo.GetFileSystemEntry(pathEntry)

let isRegular = fileStat.IsRegularFile
```