# .net core how to synchronize permissions between 2 files (or directory)

Tags: c#, .net-core, permissions

How to synchronize file permissions between 2 files in `.net core 3.0`

This problem when I do make a automatic update progrom. I need to synchronize the previous file permissions to the updated file (It could also be a directory)

For example, the updated shell script needs to be consistent with the permissions of the previous shell script, otherwise it will not work (because the executable permission is missing)

I try to use `GetAccessControl` and `SetAccessControl`, but in **macos**, It throws `NotSupportedException`

```cs
var security = new DirectoryInfo(older).GetAccessControl();
new DirectoryInfo(newer).SetAccessControl(security);
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using [FileSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41019841/12258072)?

Comment: @Longoon12000 Filesecurity can be create manually, but how to get the previous permissions