# Set running user as file owner and delete it in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, acl, windows-server

I've made a File Cleaner Windows Service (using [.NET Core 3 Worker Service hosted in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)). I set the service to run as Administrator with Full Access.

Now I have two IIS websites running by `IIS APP POOL\foo` and `IIS APP POOL\bar` user respectively. Each site has their own `C:\web\foo\Uploads\` and `C:\web\bar\Uploads\` folders that I want my File Cleaner to periodically delete them.

Even though I set Full Control permission for `Uploads` folders for `Administrator`, newly created files by `foo` and `bar` are still not deletable by Administrator. I can manually change owner of the files in these folder then delete them (interestingly, in File Explorer, I can just Delete them without any problem), but I don't know how to programmatically do it.

Given that I can give any permission to my running app, how can I set a folder/file owner/full control to the account running it and then delete it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify file access control in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449973/how-to-modify-file-access-control-in-net-core)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have seen that article before, but don't know how to get the credential of the currently running account (not sure if it's even possible).

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for your lead. From that one and many other articles I have come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Heretic Monkey [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449973/how-to-modify-file-access-control-in-net-core) and the information from various StackOverflow post, I compiled the solution both for setting the file/folder owner and reset its attributes (i.e readonly, system):

```
public static class CoreUtils
{

    public static string RunningUser { get; } = $"{Environment.UserDomainName}\\{Environment.UserName}";
    public static NTAccount RunningAccount { get; } = new NTAccount(Environment.UserDomainName, Environment.UserName);

}

void SetOwner(FileInfo file)
{
    var acl = file.GetAccessControl(System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.All);

    acl.SetOwner(CoreUtils.RunningAccount);
    acl.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
        CoreUtils.RunningUser, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

    file.SetAccessControl(acl);
}
```

Also a note is that as in linked article, the API does not support long file name so you need extra processing if your app needs to work with these files.