# Get Domain Groups that have read access to a file in .net 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

The following code does not work in .**net 6 class library**, because **File.GetAccessControl** method is not available in .**net 6**.

I need a function that will retrieve all the domain user groups that have **read access** to a file.

```
public List<string> GetFileReadGroups(string filePath)
        {
            var fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(filePath);
            var readRules = fileSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            var groups = new List<string>();
            foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in readRules)
            {
                if ((rule.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ReadData) == FileSystemRights.ReadData)
                {
                    if (rule.IdentityReference is SecurityIdentifier sid)
                    {
                        var account = (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
                        groups.Add(account.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            return groups;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify file access control in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449973/how-to-modify-file-access-control-in-net-core)

Comment: Looking into it