# In C# how can i get the access rights of a folder?

Tags: c#, .net, tree, filesystems

i want to make a C# recursiv File Analytic Program. I also used Spectre Console for a clearer view of my Tree. I want to add some more data to this program, but somehow i cant get more infos out of my directoryInfo.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path= @"C:\Users\MogliMehmet\Desktop\Test";

        Tree tree =new Tree(path);

        TraverseTree(path, tree);

        AnsiConsole.Write(tree);

    }

    private static void TraverseTree(string path,IHasTreeNodes node)
    {
       DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        var dirNode = node.AddNode(new Markup("[blue]" + dir.Name + "[/]"));
        dirNode.AddNode(new Markup("Erstellt am: "+"[green]" + dir.CreationTime + "[/]" + " Letzter Zugriff:" + "[green]" + dir.LastAccessTime + "[/]" + " Zuletzt geändert:" + "[green]" + dir.LastWriteTime + "[/]"));

        FileInfo[] files=dir.GetFiles();
        if (files.Length>0)
        {
            var filesNode = dirNode.AddNode("Dateien");

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                filesNode.AddNode(new Markup("DateiName: " + "[yellow]" + file.FullName + "[/]" + " Letzter Zugriff:" + "[yellow]" + file.LastAccessTime + "[/]" + " Zuletzt geändert:" + "[yellow]" + file.LastWriteTime + "[/]"));
            }

        }

        DirectoryInfo[] dirs=dir.GetDirectories();
        if (dirs.Length>0)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dirSingle in dirs)
            {
                TraverseTree(dirSingle.FullName, dirNode);
            }   
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: On Net Core you need one of the [GetAccessControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemaclextensions.getaccesscontrol?view=net-8.0#system-io-filesystemaclextensions-getaccesscontrol(system-io-directoryinfo)) extension methods. You need the System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl nuget package for that. In old .Net Framework DirectoryInfo should already have a GetAccessControl method. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449973/how-to-modify-file-access-control-in-net-core) question might have some interesting code samples for you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone have a similar problem, here is my solution:

This for the traverse function:

```
DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = dir.GetAccessControl();                           
dirNode.AddNode(new Markup("Zugriffsrechte Typ: " + "[red]" + GetAccessRights(dirSecurity) + "[/]"));
```

This is the `GetAccessRights` function:

```
    private static string GetAccessRights(DirectorySecurity dirSecurity)
    {
        AuthorizationRuleCollection accessRules = dirSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));

        string accessInfo = "";

        foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in accessRules)
        {
            accessInfo += $"Idendität: {rule.IdentityReference}, Zugriffsrechte Typ: {rule.AccessControlType}, Datei Berechtigungen: {rule.FileSystemRights}\n";
        }

        return accessInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**